# Mark different cell when a certain key is pressed (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I don't know if there are any duplicates of this questions since I didn't even know how to look it up so please tell me if this question already exists.
So what I have is the following: I have a table, if you hover over one cell of the table, that cell is supposed to turn red. What I want to do is:

- **One** cell above/ under or next to it is supposed to turn red as well, but only one of them, as I said
- when pressing a certain key, another cell is supposed to turn red

So in the end, you're supposed to be able to "go around" that one cell by clicking on a certain key. I know how to detect if a key has been pressed but I'm not sure about how to go about the part where it switches cells. I was thinking about something along the lines of:

```
function myFunction (event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey) {
        //First cell becomes red
        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            //Second cell becomes red
        }
    }
};
```

...And so on, however, I don't know if that's very efficient and if there's no better way to do it. I'm very much of an amateur so help is very appreciated! Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Edit: Here's the HTML for the table (hope it's not too long)

```
<div id="playerBoard" class="col-md-6 gameBoard">
        <table id="targetLocation">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>F</th>
                <th>G</th>
                <th>H</th>
                <th>I</th>
                <th>J</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th> 
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <th>6</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <th>7</th> 
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <th>8</th> 
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <th>9</th> 
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <th>10</th>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
                <td><button class="cells" onmouseover="getTarget(this)">O</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: We need to see what this table looks like and you need to brush up on the DOM API.

Comment: To start with, you haven't closed your `myFunction()`,  it's missing a `}` and both your `if()` conditions will return true if the `CTRL` key is pressed...

Comment: Definitely need to see the table. Also, some considerations are whether the table structure is consistent? Will it have `colspan` or `rowspan` cells? How should they be handled if you do? What if the selected cell is the left or right most cell, hence there is nothing to the right or left?

Comment: @NewToJS thanks for the comment, I updated my code acccordingly! And that was the intention, I mean I wanted to use the CRTL key specifically
@ fubar will edit my post in a sec to add the html for the table. If the cell is an outermost cell, only 3 (or 2, in case of an edge) options should be available

Comment: @A.S.J can you try be more clear and explain the expected output of the `ctrl` key because myself and would appear others aren't too clear on what you want to do once the `ctrl` key is pressed? Also are you wanting the background to stay selected/red or go back to it's original color on mouse out?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this time I could understand your aim correctly, and I have changed my code, please be sure that click any place at first otherwise ctrKey doesn't work. You can check on code snippet

**Styles**

```
    td>button.cells:hover{
        background-color: red;
    }
    td>button.cells.selected{
        background-color: pink;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="playerBoard" class="col-md-6 gameBoard">
<table id="targetLocation" cellpadding="3" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>H</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>J</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>6</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>7</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var activeCell = null;
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {//cells.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.onmouseover = function (evt) {
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {//cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            cell.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        activeCell = evt.target;
    }
    cell.onmouseout = function (evt) {
        activeCell = null;
    }
});
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 17 && activeCell != null) {
        if(activeCell.classList.contains('cells')) {
            var activeTd = activeCell.parentElement;
            var activeTr = activeCell.parentElement.parentElement;
            var rowsTr = document.querySelectorAll('#targetLocation tr');
            var leftCell = null;
            var rightCell = null;
            var upCell = null;
            var downCell = null;
            var x = null;
            var y = null;
            x = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(activeTr.children,activeTd)
            y = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(rowsTr,activeTr)
            console.log(x);
            console.log(y);
            if(x>1){
                leftCell = activeTr.children[x-1].children[0];
            }
            console.log(leftCell);
            if(x<10){
                rightCell = activeTr.children[x+1].children[0];
            }
            console.log(rightCell);
            if(y>1){
                upCell = rowsTr[y-1].children[x].children[0];
            }
            console.log(upCell);
            if(y<10){
                downCell = rowsTr[y+1].children[x].children[0];
            }
            console.log(downCell);
            if(leftCell){
                if (!leftCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    leftCell.classList.add('selected');
                }
            }
            if(rightCell){
                if (!rightCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    rightCell.classList.add('selected');
                }
            }
            if(upCell){
                if (!upCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    upCell.classList.add('selected');
                }
            }
            if(downCell){
                if (!downCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    downCell.classList.add('selected');
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {
            cell.classList.remove('selected');
        });
    }
};
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 17) {
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {
            cell.classList.remove('selected');
        });
    }
};
```

```js
    var activeCell = null;
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {//cells.forEach(function (cell) {
        cell.onmouseover = function (evt) {
            var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {//cells.forEach(function (cell) {
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
            });
            activeCell = evt.target;
        }
        cell.onmouseout = function (evt) {
            activeCell = null;
        }
    });
    document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.which === 17 && activeCell != null) {
            if(activeCell.classList.contains('cells')) {
                var activeTd = activeCell.parentElement;
                var activeTr = activeCell.parentElement.parentElement;
                var rowsTr = document.querySelectorAll('#targetLocation tr');
                var leftCell = null;
                var rightCell = null;
                var upCell = null;
                var downCell = null;
                var x = null;
                var y = null;
                x = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(activeTr.children,activeTd)
                y = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(rowsTr,activeTr)
                console.log(x);
                console.log(y);
                if(x>1){
                    leftCell = activeTr.children[x-1].children[0];
                }
                console.log(leftCell);
                if(x<10){
                    rightCell = activeTr.children[x+1].children[0];
                }
                console.log(rightCell);
                if(y>1){
                    upCell = rowsTr[y-1].children[x].children[0];
                }
                console.log(upCell);
                if(y<10){
                    downCell = rowsTr[y+1].children[x].children[0];
                }
                console.log(downCell);
                if(leftCell){
                    if (!leftCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                        leftCell.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                }
                if(rightCell){
                    if (!rightCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                        rightCell.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                }
                if(upCell){
                    if (!upCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                        upCell.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                }
                if(downCell){
                    if (!downCell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                        downCell.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
            });
        }
    };
    document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.which === 17) {
            var cells = document.querySelectorAll('button.cells.selected');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell, index) {
                cell.classList.remove('selected');
            });
        }
    };
```

```css
        td>button.cells:hover{
            background-color: red;
        }
        td>button.cells.selected{
            background-color: pink;
        }
```

```html
<div id="playerBoard" class="col-md-6 gameBoard">
    <table id="targetLocation" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>H</th>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>J</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>6</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>7</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>8</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>9</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>10</th>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
            <td><button class="cells">O</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: I have added a snippet of your source code so the OP and others can run/test it without having to copy/paste the source code.

Comment: Note that querySelectorAll() returns a `NodeList`, not an array. The NodeList object has also a method called `forEach()`, but only new browsers supports it. According to MDN, IE does not support it.

Comment: @StanE Thanks for your awareness and I have updated the code with Array.prototype.forEach

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ One other things I have noticed. When pressing the `CTRL` key I can't seem to work out what it is doing.... I see no change what so ever.

Comment: Sorry i think i misunderstood the question i understood with click

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ I think most are misunderstanding the purpose/expectations of the `CTRL` key. Awaiting for more information.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding,  @A.S.J

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly what your after.

But if you hover the cells will turn red, pressing the cursor keys will highlight the cell in the direction selected in pink.

Please note, click the snippet window to focus it for keyboard events to trigger.

```js
let selected = null;

const table = document.createElement("table");
for (let y = 0; y < 6; y ++) {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(tr);
  for (let x = 0; x < 6; x ++) {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    td.dataset.pos = `${x}:${y}`;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}
document.body.appendChild(table);


document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (ev) {
  selected = ev.target;
}, true);

const keys = {
  "ArrowDown": { y: +1 },
  "ArrowUp": { y: -1 },
  "ArrowLeft": { x: -1 },
  "ArrowRight": { x: +1 }
};

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  if (!selected) return;
  const pos = selected.dataset.pos.split(":").map(Number);
  const k = keys[ev.key];
  pos[0] += k.x | 0;
  pos[1] += k.y | 0;
  table.querySelector(`[data-pos="${pos.join(":")}"]`).classList.add("selected");
}, true);

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  for (let i of table.querySelectorAll("td")) {
    i.classList.remove("selected");
  }
}, true);
```

```css
td { width:20px; height:20px; border: 1px solid black; }
td:hover { background-color: red }

.selected {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to see what the `javascript` is doing.... I see the `css` hover working but when I press `ctrl` it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: @NewToJS  Like I said I've used cursor keys, not sure what logic you want when pressing the ctrl key, how do I know up/down/left/right, or is it random.  Also make sure you click once into the snippet to get focus, or it won't get keyboard events..

Comment: Ah yes, I see the **direction keys** working. My apologies for that. I also don't fully understand the OP's expectations of the `ctrl` key either so I decided not to post a answer until I do. Good job with your answer though!

Comment: @NewToJS  Sorry, there.. Thought you was the OP.. Yeah, if we get the logic hopefully won't be too hard to update.

Comment: I have just posted another comment to the OP to try and find out. I have also asked if the OP wants to keep the background red or go back to it's original color since you have used `:hover` in your solution but the other solution has a different approach.